# Как правильно хранить в базе данных вложенные json объекты?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, json

Приветствую. Например, в базе данных мне нужно хранить объекты следующего вида:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "order": 0,
    "descr": {
        "nom": "Слово", "gen": "Слова", "abl": "Слове"
    }
    "virtual": 1
}
```

Если бы не было поля `descr`, то всё тривиально - каждому ключу соответствует столбец в таблице. Но как хранить `descr`? Можно, конечно, просто хранить в таблице json, но тогда таблица не будет соответствовать правилу о том, что каждая ячейка должна хранить единственное значение.

Answer (score 1):

Если количество ячеек в массиве descr будет постоянным, можно каждому значению выделить колонку, с поиском значений будет проще. 
Если количество ячеек будет разным и поиск по ним производиться не будет, то я бы хранил его в первоначальном виде.

Comment: Только descr  - это не массив, а объект

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от того, что вы собираетесь делать с вашими объектами. Если просто записать json в базу - прочитать json из базы, то можно ничего не делать, хранить весь json как одну строку. А если надо распарсить, разложить в БД по частям и обрабатывать части отдельно (например, делать поиск по атрибутам из `descr`), то сделайте две связанные таблицы. Первая будет хранить сам объект и иметь поля `id`, `order`, `virtual`, а вторая будет хранить описания. Поля будут, соответственно:

- `id` - первичный ключ, его надо будет генерировать отдельно
- `object_id` - внешний ключ, ссылка на объект
- `attribute` - для названий атрибутов (`nom`, `gen`, `abl`)
- `value` - для значений (`Слово`, `Слова`, `Слове`)

Для вашего json у вас будет, соответственно, одна строка в таблице объектов и 3 связанные строки в таблице описаний.